# Impedir la introducción de caracteres especiales en VisualBasic .NET

Tags: vb.net, .net, regex, visual-studio-2013

Buenas, veréis tengo el siguiente problema:
Yo quiero tener una línea en la que introduzco un nombre, formado únicamente por letras, sin números ni caracteres especiales.

La siguiente clase es una clase de prueba para comprobar que valido campos correctamente antes de usar este código en el programa principal.

Este es mi código:

```vb
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim linea As String = " "

    'Definimos expresiones regulares para controlar los input en las textbox(todos prohiben también caracteres especiales):
    Dim patronLetras As String = "[A-Za-z]"   'Solo letras
    Dim patronNum As String = "[1-9]"  'Solo números
    Dim patronMixto As String = "[A-Za-z1-9]"  'Ambos
    Dim caractEspecial = "ºª\!|@#·$%&/()=?¿¡,;.:-_<>[]{}*+"

    While (linea <> "fin")
        linea = Console.ReadLine()

        Dim rgx As New Regex(patronLetras)
        Dim matchTlf As Match = rgx.Match(linea)
        If (matchTlf.Success = False Or linea.Contains(caractEspecial) = True) Then
            Console.WriteLine("No coincide")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Coincide")
        End If
    End While

End Sub

End Module
```

El bloque IF debería decir que coinciden aquellos Strings que sean únicamente letras.
En este momento estoy utilizando la expresión patronLetras para validar únicamente letras mayúsculas y minúsculas de la a a la z, y lo que me ocurre es:

- Si introduzco letras("adfadsfvvrevHAGSDCVV"), COINCIDE.
- si introduzco un carácter especial o un número(181), NO coincide.
- si introduzco letras y caracteres especiales(asdfTYER.-$), COINCIDE.
- si introduzco letras y números(hgvsdGASVD5352456), COINCIDE.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que estos dos últimos puntos no ocurran, puesto que yo solo quiero letras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomendaría que en vez de explicitar lo que NO puede ingresarse, te concentres en lo que sí. Por darte un ejemplo, si escribiera Pa~blo o Pa^blo, tu código fallaría, aunque logres corregir el problema.

Lo que podrías hacer es validar que el input sean solo letras de esta forma:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias, estaba tan cegado intentando sacar cosas de ahi que ni lo pense de esta manera.

Comment: Nos suele pasar y siempre un segundo punto de vista ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a ver así:

```
Dim patronNum As New Regex("[0-9]")
Dim caractEspecial As New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")

If patronNum.Matches(linea).Count > 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("No coincide")
        Return False
    End If

    If caractEspecial.Matches(linea).Count > 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("No coincide")
        Return False
    End If
```

Lo que haces es que cuentas los números/caracteres especiales de `linea` y si hay mas de 0 dices que "No coincide". El `Return False` lo he puesto por si estás en algún bucle o algo, pero para tu ejemplo de código no te haría falta en un principio.
Es simple, espero que te sirva. Y comprueba tu código, porque éstas mirando solo la posibilidad del `1 al 9` obviando el 0.

> Dim patronNum As String = "[1-9]"  'Solo números'

Comment: Vaya! Cierto muchas gracias, ni me había dado cuenta de lo del 0.

Answer (score 1):

También se puede validar así. (La expesión regular se tomó de la página
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format)

```
Public Shared Function ValidarCorreo(ByVal correo As String) As Boolean
        Dim sreg As String = "^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$"
        Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex(sreg)
        Dim rgxok As Match = rgx.Match(correo)
        Return rgxok.Success
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim linea As String = " "

    'Definimos expresiones regulares para controlar los input en las textbox(todos prohiben también caracteres especiales):
    Dim patronNum As String = "[0-9]"  'Solo números
    Dim patronCharEspeciales As String = "[^\w]"  'Caracteres Especiales

    While (linea <> "fin")
        linea = Console.ReadLine()

        Dim rgx As New Regex(patronNum)
        Dim matchTlf As Match = rgx.Match(linea)
        Dim rgx2 As New Regex(patronCharEspeciales)
        Dim matchTlf2 As Match = rgx2.Match(linea)

        If (matchTlf.Success = True Or matchTlf2.Success = True) Then
            Console.WriteLine("No coincide")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Coincide")
        End If
    End While

End Sub

End Module
```

No soy un experto en expresiones regulares, así que seguro que puedes escribirlo con una sola expresión regular en lugar de 2.

Lo que estamos haciendo es, primero comprobar si tiene números en su estructura, y luego comprobar sino esta formada por caracteres alphanuméricos, y en caso de que cualquiera de estas dos clausulas sea ciertas decir que no coincide.